# How to normalize time series data with multiple features by using sklearn?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

For data with the shape `(num_samples,features)`, `MinMaxScaler` from `sklearn.preprocessing` can be used to normalize it easily.

However, when using the same method for time series data with the shape `(num_samples, time_steps,features)`, sklearn will give an error.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np

#Making artifical time data
x1 = np.linspace(0,3,4).reshape(-1,1)
x2 = np.linspace(10,13,4).reshape(-1,1)
X1 = np.concatenate((x1*0.1,x2*0.1),axis=1)
X2 = np.concatenate((x1,x2),axis=1)
X = np.stack((X1,X2))

#Trying to normalize
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_norm = scaler.fit_transform(X) <--- error here
```

> ValueError: Found array with dim 3. MinMaxScaler expected <= 2.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256930/python-how-to-normalize-time-series-data) suggests something like

```
(timeseries-timeseries.min())/(timeseries.max()-timeseries.min())
```

Yet, it only works for data with only 1 feature. Since my data has more than 1 feature, this method doesn't work.

How to normalize time series data with multiple features?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59601298/10375049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To normalize a 3D tensor of shape (n_samples, timesteps, n_features) use the following:

```
(timeseries-timeseries.min(axis=2))/(timeseries.max(axis=2)-timeseries.min(axis=2))
```

Using the argument axis=2 will return the result of the tensor operation performed along the 3rd dimension i.e., the feature axis. Thus each feature will be normalized independently.